# Django : show the username to the user when logged in

Tags: django

How can I show any user his/her username when logged in at "next.html" page ???

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': 'Email or Password is incorrect'})

    user_profile = User_account.objects.filter(e_mail = request.POST['user_email'],     passwd = request.POST['password'])     
    if user_profile:
        return render(request, 'next.html', {'name' :User_account.objects.**WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE???** } )
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': 'Email or Password is incorrect'})
```

Answer (score 21):

There are 2 ways you can do it:

a) Directly in the template:

```
{{request.user.username}}
```

Or:
b)

```
return render(request, 'next.html', {'name' : request.user.username })
```

Note that you have not "logged" the user in yet

In your case, you can do:

```
return render(request, 'next.html', {'name' : user_account.first_name })
```

You need to call the [`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) method to actually log the user in, or manually handle the login. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page) can give you the way to do it.

Also you would need a [request_context processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470179/module-django-core-context-processors-does-not-define-a-auth-callable-reques)

Comment: He's also gonna need request context processor enabled.

Comment: I wrote 
    return render(request, 'next.html', {'name' : user_account.username })

but it doesn't work

Comment: how is you User_account model defined?

Comment: from django.db import models

    class User_account(models.Model):
       first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       e_mail = models.EmailField()
       passwd = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name

Comment: you dont have a username field. What do you want to show as username ?

Comment: In my opinion, you should inherit from `django.contrib.auth.models.User` Read up about it in the django documentation

Comment: I still believe you got the whole models wrong. Read the documentation again. The django contrib auth models does what you are looking to do, and a lot more

Comment: {{request.user.username}} worked flawlessly. Thank you!