# Django Pagination corrupted all the paths to all the .css and .js elements

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

I was looking to use [django-pagination](https://github.com/ericflo/django-pagination), and I applied all the changes to settings.py after installing django=pagination but when I ran my server and accesssed the page, pagination has arrived for sure, but it broke all the paths to css and js elements. Thus the page is void of any design. I really cant understand what happened. Heres the output at `python manage.py runserver` :

```
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11594
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /style/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3213
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /style/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3189
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /style/tabs.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3186
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3189
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/jq.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3168
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /images/green_btn_main.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3219
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3180
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/bootstrap-tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3213
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/bootstrap-popover.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3213
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/bootstrap-tab.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3201
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /images/green_btn-2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3210
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3189
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3180
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /images/green_btn-2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3210
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /images/green_btn_main.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3219
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/bootstrap-tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3213
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/bootstrap-popover.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3213
[29/Jun/2013 10:26:53] "GET /js/bootstrap-tab.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3201
```

And heres the part of `git diff` of the `settings.py` which was modified:

```
@@ -95,6 +95,8 @@ MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
+    'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
+    
     # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
     # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 )
@@ -127,6 +129,7 @@ INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'rest_framework',
     'south',
     'ui',
+    'pagination',
  )
+
+TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
+    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
+    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
+    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
+    'django.core.context_processors.media',
+    'django.core.context_processors.request',
+)
```

Yes in the `django-pagination` docs it is said to use `django.core.context_processors.auth` and not `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`
But I used the former when I hit an error which was correctly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470179/module-django-core-context-processors-does-not-define-a-auth-callable-reques). Its about being on `Django 1.4`. yes I am on `1.4` Someone please help me. All the UI design has vanished with only the texts.

**Update:** I did a `git stash` to undo my changes and all the elements load up fine. It must be one of the lines in the `settings.py` file. Can someone pint out which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost `"django.core.context_processors.static"`, so you got a lot of 404.

[Default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` is:

```
("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

The solution of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233283/995394) may be a better practice.

Comment: I read its docs again, and it said to only add `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` if its not already defined. So I removed this from the settings.py and it worked! But I will accept your answer because this also looks like a possible solution. +1!

Comment: Yes, you can leave it not defined or change it based on the default.